# how to prohibit the access to a module variable in global scope but allow access inside another module? (javaScript)

Tags: javascript, module, factory, tic-tac-toe

I am new to javascript and am currently doing a tic tac toe project(please refer to -> https://www.theodinproject.com/lessons/node-path-javascript-tic-tac-toe).

This is my live project link (https://shivakharbanda.github.io/tic-tac-toe/).

According to the project specifications(mentioned in the above link), I am using modules("Your main goal here is to have as little global code as possible. Try tucking everything away inside of a module or factory. Rule of thumb: if you only ever need ONE of something (gameBoard, displayController), use a module. If you need multiples of something (players!), create them with factories.")

this is my app.js code. here I am creating an array inside gameBoard module to store the tic-tac toe configuration and accessing it inside the displayController(module for controlling the whole game logic).

I want to prohibit access to my `gameBoardArr` variable in the global scope and at the same time allow it to be accessed and changed inside my `displayController`  module.

this is my gameBoard Module

```
let gameBoard = (function(){
    'use strict';
    var gameBoardArr = ["","","","","","","","",""];


    var gameBoardDisplay = () => {

        let gameboxes = [...document.querySelectorAll(".td")];
        //console.log(gameboxes)
        gameboxes.forEach(Element=> {
            let index = Element.id;

            //console.log(gameBoard.gameBoardArr);
            if (gameBoard.gameBoardArr[index] == "X"){
                Element.textContent = "⨉"
            } else if (gameBoard.gameBoardArr[index] == "O") {
                Element.textContent = "◯"
            } else {
                Element.textContent = gameBoard.gameBoardArr[index];
            }
            
        })

    }

    return {gameBoardDisplay, gameBoardArr};
})();
```

this is my player factory

```
let gamePlayer = (playerSymbol) => {
    let player = playerSymbol;

    return {player}
}
```

this is my displayController

```
let displayController = (function () {


    gameBoard.gameBoardDisplay();

    let _count = 0;
    
    let _gameDiv = document.querySelector(".game-board");

    let _welcomePanel = document.querySelector(".welcome");

    let _selectionBtn1 = document.querySelector(".btn-1");
    let _selectionBtn2 = document.querySelector(".btn-2");

    var _resetBoard = () => {
        gameBoard.gameBoardArr = ["","","","","","","","",""];
        gameBoard.gameBoardDisplay();
        _count = 0;
    }

    var _congratulateWinner = (winnerName) => {


        
        playNextRoundBtn = document.createElement("button");
        playNextRoundBtn.classList.add("play-next-round")
        playNextRoundBtn.textContent = "Play Next Round"

        //console.log("winnerbox");
        winnerBox = document.querySelector(".congratulations");
        winnerBox.textContent = "";

        fullscreenbox = document.querySelector(".full-screenbox");
        fullscreenbox.classList.remove("dont-show");
        congratulationMsg = document.createElement("h1");

        if (winnerName == "DRAW") {
            congratulationMsg.textContent = `Game Drawn`;
        } else {
            congratulationMsg.textContent = `congratulations ${winnerName}!`
        };
       
    
        //console.log(referenceNode);
        winnerBox.appendChild(congratulationMsg);
        winnerBox.appendChild(playNextRoundBtn);

        setTimeout(function(){
            playNextRoundBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
                setTimeout(5000);
                fullscreenbox.classList.add("dont-show");
            });
        }, 50);
        
        

    };

    var _checkWinner = (whatMark) => {
    
        //console.log(arr);
        let winningConfigs = [
            [2, 5, 8],
            [0, 4, 8],
            [0, 1, 2],
            [0, 3, 6],
            [1, 4, 7],
            [2, 4, 6],
            [3, 4, 5],
            [6, 7, 8]
        ]

        for (i = 0; i < winningConfigs.length; i ++) {
            //console.log(winningConfigs[i][0])

            //console.log(arr[winningConfigs[i][0]]);
            //console.log(whatMark);
            //console.log(arr[winningConfigs[i][0]] == whatMark);
            if (gameBoard.gameBoardArr[winningConfigs[i][0]] == whatMark && gameBoard.gameBoardArr[winningConfigs[i][1]] == whatMark && gameBoard.gameBoardArr[winningConfigs[i][2]] == whatMark) {

                return "win"
            } ;

            
        };
        

    };
    function _nextStep() {
        _gameDiv.classList.remove("dont-show");
        _welcomePanel.classList.add("dont-show");
    }

    function _HumanVHuman() {
        player1 = gamePlayer("X");
        player2 = gamePlayer("O");

        chanceFlag = true;

        cells = [...document.querySelectorAll(".td")];
        
        cells.forEach(cell =>{
            cell.addEventListener("click", ()=>{

                if (chanceFlag && gameBoard.gameBoardArr[cell.id] == "") {
                    gameBoard.gameBoardArr[cell.id] = "X";
                    _count = _count + 1
                    //console.log(gameBoard.gameBoardArr);
                    chanceFlag = false;
                } else if (!chanceFlag && gameBoard.gameBoardArr[cell.id] == ""){
                    gameBoard.gameBoardArr[cell.id] = "O";
                    _count = _count + 1
                    chanceFlag = true;
                }
                
                gameBoard.gameBoardDisplay();
                //console.log(chanceFlag);
                //console.log(gameBoard.gameBoardArr)
                setTimeout(function(){
                    let winStatus = _checkWinner(chanceFlag?"O":"X");

                    if (winStatus == "win" && chanceFlag == false) {
                        _congratulateWinner("Player 1");

                        _resetBoard();
                    } else if (winStatus == "win" && chanceFlag == true) {
                        _congratulateWinner("Player 2");
                        _resetBoard();
                        
                    } else if (_count == 9) {
                        console.log("first here");
                        _congratulateWinner("DRAW");
                        _resetBoard();
                    };
                }, 50);

                
                //console.log(_count);
                
                

            });
        });
    };

    function startGame() {
        _selectionBtn1.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
            setTimeout(function(){
                let gameMode = "HVH";
                _nextStep();
                _HumanVHuman();
                //console.log(gameMode);
                }, 50);   
        });
        
        _selectionBtn2.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
            let gameMode = "HVA";

            //console.log(gameMode);

        });
    };
    
    return {startGame};

})();
```

this code is in global scope.

```
displayController.startGame();
```

Comment: "_to have as little global code as possible_" Just put everything in modules, you don't need to write anything to the global namespace. Modules create their own namespace, the global environment can't see inside the modules.

Comment: Ooooh i see. So i can run the code directly from the module. Thanks 

Comment: but how can I hide variables from the global namespace and still can use different modules? like if I want I can go to the console and change "GameBoardArr" if I want. I want to prohibit it and still be able to use "GameBoardArr" in another module

Comment: I don't quite get your problem. Like said, any script with type of module, an inline script or linked to an external js file, creates its own namespace, and any imported module inside that script is enclosed within that namespace, nothing is global. See [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/c9of6ab4/), that might shed some light how the modules work.